# CoreAudio: Full list of "listenable" properties?

Tags: ios, macos, audio, properties, core-audio

From CoreAudio documentation, I thought callbacks can be registered to listen to changes made to any properties. But this turned out to be false hope. Seems many properties will refuse to get registered with a callback.

However, I cannot find a full list of "listenable" properties. Is there a way I can get it or is trial-and-error the only thing I can do?